# Calculate iPhone Camera line-of-sight angle (relative to North) when picture is taken

Tags: ios, camera

How can I get camera line-of-sight angle (relative to North, in degrees, zero being north, 180 being south) when a picture is taken using an iPhone (and not where the device is moving) ?

For example, I am walking towards north (0 degrees), taking a picture to my right, (which is 90 degrees), and I want that 90 degrees as my result, because that is the iPhone line-of-sight angle relative to north.

Somewhat accurate result within +/- 20 degrees is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gyroscope API in ios.

See this tuto for example : http://ios-programming.blogspot.fr/2011/11/gyroscope-accelerometer-ios-sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

Use CMMotionManager class for receiving motion data. Don't forget to include CoreMotion framework.

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

- (void)startProcess
{
    CMMotionManager *motionManager = [CMMotionManager new];
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = .2;

    if (motionManager.deviceMotionAvailable ) {
        NSOperationQueue *motionQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        CMAttitudeReferenceFrame attitudeFrame = CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical;
        [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:attitudeFrame
                                                           toQueue:motionQueue
                                                       withHandler:^ (CMDeviceMotion *newMotionData, NSError *newError) {
                                                    CMAcceleration gravity = motionData.gravity;
                                                    CGFloat rotation = [self rotationForGravity:gravity];
                                                });          
                                           }];
    }

- (CGFloat)rotationForGravity:(CMAcceleration)customGravity
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        return customGravity.y;
    else
        return -customGravity.y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pablo for the detailed answer. I made a mistake describing the problem. I want the iPhone camera line-of-sight relative to true north (NOT where the device is moving too). For example, I am walking towards north 0degrees, taking a picture to right, which is 90deg, and I want that 90deg as my result, because that is the iPhone line-of-sight angle relative to north.

Comment: Oh, then you can probably use motionData.magneticField instead of gravity and rotation, haven't tested it but it should give you the radians from North. Hope this helps.